# rosdoc and wiki updates

Tags: ros, rosdoc, documentation, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What needs to happen for rosdoc to automatically find and generate stuff for a PackageHeader on the wiki? Specifically, I'm making the wiki page for pr2_marker_control, which is in trunk of pr2_object_manipulation, and it still says "Newly proposed, mistyped, or obsolete package. Could not find package "pr2_marker_control" in rosdoc."

I suspect this is because the released version of pr2_object_manipulation is a branch; does rosdoc only look through specific branches of stacks?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10214/rosdoc-and-wiki-updates/) by [aleeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/35/aleeper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 573 on 2011-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosdoc indexer is controlled by this rosinstall file:

https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/rosorg/trunk/rosdoc_rosorg/repos.rosinstall

The rosinstall file can be updated by people with commit access (usually me).

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1